# I want use switch button by using that I want access oneViewController to secondViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I want to use UISwitch from that when isON use it should be in ViewController1 isOFF then it has to go next ViewController. Can someone help me on this?

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth


class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var citiPostSwitch:UISwitch!

    @IBAction func switchToCitiPost (switchState: UISwitch){
        if citiPostSwitch.isOn{
            print("your in ViewConroller 1")
            citiPostSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)

        } else{
            citiPostSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
            print("your in ViewController 2")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func logOutAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            do {
                try Auth.auth().signOut()
                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
                present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple have specific use cases for the UI components they supply. A switch should be used to have something on or off, set or not set, etc. It’s isn’t suited to moving between viewControllers. Why aren’t You using a button or even a tabbarController?

Comment: Are you want display viewcontroller 1 when switch is on and display viewcontroller 2 when switch is off ? Am i right?

Comment: @Magnas yes we can use those too but I want to use switch only is that possible

Comment: @Sanjukta Yes I use Switch in homeViewController when I use a switch on it has to go homeNewViewController

Comment: @Ranjith iOS Yes, of course it is possible but I still don't understand why. Apple's Human Interface Guidelines make it clear that you should try not to use interface elements in a way that user's do not expect. Switching viewControllers is NOT the job of a switch.

Comment: ok Thank you @Magnas I will implement using a button

Answer (score -1):

In your function , just off the switch of this and second controller, in which your are navigating.

```
@IBAction func switchToCitiPost (switchState: UISwitch){
    if citiPostSwitch.isOn {
        citiPostSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
        let vc = SecondViewController()
        vc.switch.setOn(false, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

When your come to your controller you  will get your switch in off state.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var `switch`: UISwitch!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.switch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchAction(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func switchAction(_ switchState: UISwitch) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }    
}
```

In SecondView Controller , on switch action just dismiss or pop from Controller.
Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Vijay Thank you but i got error   is 1. Value of type 'HomeNewViewController' has no member 'delegate' 2.Value of type 'HomeNewViewController' has no member 'switch' 3.Cannot convert value of type 'HomeNewViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Comment: @RanjitiOS I have updated the answer now it work fine

Comment: hi @ Vijay Thank You, in secondviewController I got error:  1 Use of undeclared type 'SetSwitchState' can you help me